# How to override properties in a derived class using generics

Tags: vb.net, generics

I have the following class setup and I don't understand why it won't compile.

I get the following error on "Public Overrides Property F As T"

- 'Public Overrides Property F As T' cannot override 'Public Overridable Property F As X' because they differ in return types.
- This confuses me because I constrained T to be derived from X.

Can someone explain how I can accomplish this goal?  In the end I need to have Class A and Class B where B inherits from A.  Where A has an overridable property F of type X, and B overrides F with a type that is derived from X.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  If this cannot be done, I'd be interested to know why (limitation of .NET?) and how I should go about this.

```
Public Class X
End Class

Public Class Y
    Inherits X
End Class

Public Class A
    Public Overridable Property F As X
End Class

Public Class A(Of T As X)
    Inherits A
    Public Overrides Property F As T
End Class

Public Class B
    Inherits A(Of Y)
    Public Overrides Property F As Y
End Class
```

Thank-you!

Comment: Why do you need this if you constrain it to `X` or any of its descendants anyway?

Comment: @VisualVincent - I didn't include the overridable functions in these classes.  They each do work specific to the class they are in.  Basically Class B has business logic in it specific to one use case based on the values in B.F.  Whereas, it's fine for all other instances to fall back to A and do the work as defined in A.

Comment: "Nice names" even for SO sample ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that does what I'm after using the Shadows keyword.

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim a As New A()
        Dim b As New B()

        a.F = New X()
        b.F = New Y()

        Dim c As New Container()
        c.Value = a

        Console.WriteLine(c)        

        c.Value = b

        Console.WriteLine(c)        
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class Container
    Public Value As A
    Public Overrides Function ToString() AS String
        Return Value.ToString()
    End Function
End Class

Public Class X
    Public Overrides Function ToString() AS String
        Return "X"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Y
    Inherits X
    Public Overrides Function ToString() AS String
        Return "Y"
    End Function
End Class


Public Class A
    Public Overridable Property F As X
    Public Overrides Function ToString() AS String
        Return "A" + F.ToString()
    End Function
End Class

Public Class B
    Inherits A
    Public Shadows Property F As Y
    Public Overrides Function ToString() AS String
        Return "B" + F.ToString()
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

New answer. I don't think it's possible (exactly as you requested it), namely `B overrides F with a type that is derived from X`, as you saw.

But you could hold Y in a private field in B and expose it through F. Then you'd need to cast F to Y to access whatever functionality Y provides over X. This can be done without changing A.

```
Public Class X
    Public Overridable Function Z() As String
        Return "X"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Y
    Inherits X
    Public Overrides Function Z() As String
        Return "Y"
    End Function
    Public Function Foo() As String
        Return "Bar"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class A
    Public Overridable Property F As X
End Class

Public Class B
    Inherits A
    Private _f As Y
    Public Overrides Property F As X
        Get
            Return _f
        End Get
        Set(value As X)
            _f = DirectCast(value, X)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim a As New A()
Dim x As New X()
Dim b As New B()
Dim y As New Y()

a.F = x
Console.WriteLine(a.F.Z)
' Console.WriteLine(DirectCast(a.F, Y).Foo()) ' InvalidCastException

b.F = y
Console.WriteLine(b.F.Z)
Console.WriteLine(DirectCast(b.F, Y).Foo()) ' OK
```

Output

> X
>   
> Y
>   
> Bar

Comment: The issue with that is that this is part of a larger code base that heavily relies on using Class A as it is.  I have considered making that change, but it means making sweeping changes to everything that references A.  The more I change, the more unexpected consequences.

Comment: @JeremyFriesen : Since `Y` inherits `X` you can set `F = Y` even if it's declared as `F As X`. To use the actual `Y` just check its type: `If F.GetType() Is GetType(Y) Then : DirectCast(F, Y).DoStuff() : End If`.

Comment: @JeremyFriesen : Here's a fiddle showing what I just described: https://dotnetfiddle.net/a4jqbQ (this works anywhere and in any derived class, and you _don't have_ to do it in the property's `Set` method)

Comment: @VisualVincent : I see how that approach works, but I can't use it as it requires Class X to be 'aware' of the existence of Class Y.  This may not seem like a big problem, until someone else comes along and decides to add a Class Z (Inherits from X) to do some new specific business logic.  It would be easily overlooked that Class X needs to have some code changed as well without a comment.  I'm not saying that it won't work, but I'm hoping there's a pattern out there where work done on Class X is agnostic of Class Y, and work done on Class Y can rely on Class X as a base class.

Comment: @the_lotus : This is a little beyond me.  Can you explain why, or point me to an article that explains this? Thanks!

Comment: @JeremyFriesen : No, `X` doesn't need to be aware of `Y` or `Z` at all (nor does `A`). However the code that accesses _**specific**_ members of `Y` and `Z` must be aware of their existance, but the only code that will ever do that is the same code/project that creates those two classes.

Comment: @JeremyFriesen : It all comes down to _**where**_ you want to access those methods, which is where you put the `GetType` code.